# Возможно ли будет расшифровать диск с битлокером?

Tags: windows, шифрование, диск, образ

Все данные на компьютере шифруются при помощи битлокера.

Мне интересно, если с диком что-нибудь случится и придётся с зашифрованного диска делать образ (например, при помощи `ddrescue`), то можно ли его будет расшифровать?

- Какие данные потребуются для расшифровки?
  И каким образом надо будет выполнять расшифровку образа?
- Повлияет ли наличие повреждений на расшифровку?
  Т. е. будет ли объём повреждённой части диска совпадать с объёмом, который не будет расшифрован, или же расшифровать в таком случае не получится больше?
  Может ли повредиться какая-то часть диска, из-за которой его вообще не удастся расшифровать?
- Расшифровка будет возможна только на том же компьютере или на любом?
- Как на всё вышеперечисленное влияет наличие TPM (Trusted Platform Module)?

PS: Нашёл [вот такую статью](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2014/04/15/repair-data-bitlocker-drive/), но на поставленные вопросы она что-то не очень отвечает...

Comment: Судя по информации из википедии, на каждый сектор создается свой ключ, и потом сектор шифруется в режиме CBC. Это значит, что если повредился 1 бит, то это приведет к невозможности расшифровки блока 16 байт, и следующего за ним. Другие секторы при этом можно будет восстановить.